# Undefined array key php

Tags: php

Tenho este código e da este este erro quando o $p2,$p3,$p4 excedem o array eu queria saber se  existe alguma maneira de resetar o $p2,$p3,$p4 quando chegam ao limite e voltem para o valor inicial que é 2,3,4.Se me poderem ajudar agradecia.

```
while (($data = fgetcsv($handle, 1000, ",")) !== FALSE)
            {
                $num = count($data);
                echo "<p> $num fields in line $row: <br /></p>\n";
                $row++;
                $blackpowder = $data;
                $dynamit = implode(";", $blackpowder);                            
                $pieces = explode(";", $dynamit);
                $resultadoAtletas = odbc_exec ($conn,$sql2);
                $p2=2;
                $p3=3;
                $p4=4;
                for ($c=0; $c<$NumeroAtletas; $c++)//Atleta Na Prova
                {     
                    for($j=0;$j<$Tipologia;$j++) //Numero de elementos por equipa
                    {
                        $soma++;
                        odbc_fetch_row($resultadoAtletas);
                        $col1 = $pieces[0]; //distancia
                        $col3 = $pieces[$p2]; //Time
                        $col4 = $pieces[$p3]; //Speed
                        $col5 = $pieces[$p4]; //Stroke
                        echo $col1;
                        echo "<br>";     
                        echo odbc_result($resultadoAtletas, "AtletaID");
                        echo "<br>";
                        echo $col3;
                        echo "<br>";
                        echo $col4;
                        echo "<br>";
                        echo $col5;
                        echo "<br>";  
                        echo "<br>";   
                    }    
                    $p2=$p2+4;
                    $p3=$p3+4;
                    $p4=$p4+4;
                } 
                       
            }
```

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/8676/101

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Você já tentou ver qual é o tamanho do array(pieces) e fazer uma validação antes de acessar o key.

count($pieces) >= $p4 ? "continua fazendo o que tafazendo" : "reseta o valor" :